# Convert to DateTime using c#

Tags: c#, datetime, timestamp, kendo-scheduler

I have a string which looks like 20130611T150000Z which is nothing but 2013 - 06 - 11- 15:00:00 in UTC time. How can I convert this to DateTime using c#? I am getting this value from kendoScheduler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `ParseExact` method. Example:

```
string d = "20130611T150000Z";

DateTime t = DateTime.ParseExact(d, "yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss'Z'", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```